# Master of Pores Installation Mac OS Mojave 10.14

Tags: nanopore, software-installation, nextflow

I'm bit of a newbie with ONT analyses and am having some trouble with the Master Of Pores installation instructions (https://biocorecrg.github.io/master_of_pores/install.html). I've managed to install nextflow, cloned the repository and have downloaded albacore and guppy. But when I run the pipeline below, i get an error saying
nextflow: command not found. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
curl https://get.nextflow.io | bash
mv nextflow ~/master_of_pores/NanoPreProcess/bin
nextflow run nanopreprocess.nf
```

Answer (score 3):

you should not move nextflow within `~/master_of_pores/NanoPreProcess/bin` .
Just add nextflow in your path.

```
export PATH=$PATH:where_is_your_nf_executable
```

Feel free to open an issue on github if you need more help.